# Transition input width

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have the input search field. When I click on it I need it to become wider performing smooth transition from right to left, i.e. the input is located on the right side of the page and when I click on it it should stretch to the left in some number of pixels and become wider.

Here's my css:

```
#header #search input {
background: #FFF;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
width: 178px;
height: 21px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s;
-moz-transition: all .5s;
transition: all .5s;

}
#header #search input:focus {
background: #FFF;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
width: 300px;
height: 21px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
```

Could  you help me with implementing that?

Comment: Your css should work, but I would not duplicate anything within your `:focus` selector. So within it should be your width alteration. The rest, since it's already within your 'normal' selector. Only things that are changing should be placed in the focus selector. Also note your header and search are id's (#) and not class (.) So ensure your input is within an I'd of header which has a child with I'd search which itself has a child  input

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```css
input[type="search"] {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 178px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:right;">
  <input type="search" id="search" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Position the input absolutely and set the right property to zero:

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

That forces the expansion to the left when focused.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g9pbp8xr/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Make your containers offset parents using position: relative.

```
#header, #search {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then position your input using position: absolute and place it using right.

```
#header #search input {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
    width: 178px;
    height: 21px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#header #search input:focus {
background: #FFF;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
width: 300px;
height: 21px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
```

Your animation will now stretch to the left.